# Save svg to disk as png image - browser discrepancy

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, d3.js, xml-serialization

I am trying to save to a file, as a png image, an svg plot that was created with `d3.js`. This code works fine on Chrome (saves the file to disk) but fails on Firefox 32. Any ideas why?

```
$(".savePNG").click (function() {
    var svg = ($("#svgContainer")[0]).getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
    var svg_xml = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);   // extract the data as SVG text
    var data_uri = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(svg_xml);

    var image = new Image;
    image.src = data_uri;
    image.onload = function()
    {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;

        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.clearRect(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.download = "file.png";
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        a.click ();
    };
});
```

If it provides any clue `console.log (svg_xml.length + " " + data_uri.length);`
on Chrome returns 3501304 4668434 and on Firefox 3060753 4081030. So it would seem that Firefox is missing some data but I don't know what to make of it.

Comment: In FF, `a.click()` is failing. Security restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested the `.click()` method fails for firefox. But `window.open(a.href, "_blank");` will work and open a new window with the image in it. You can right click to save it.